# Como verificar se o campo esta preenchido

Tags: java, android, actionbar

Tenho alguns EditText que devem ser preenchidos. O botão que verifica se está preenchido é um imagebutton na actionbar. eu tentei fazer de um jeito porem não funcionou.

o erro está `cnpj.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_cnpj_required));`

xml:

```
<string name="login_cnpj_required">Campo CNPJ obrigatório!</string>
```

código:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (cnpj.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
            cnpj.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_cnpj_required));
        } else if (cnpj.getText().length() < 14) {
            cnpj.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_cnpj_invalid));
        }


        if (id == R.id.action_pedido) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Como assim "não funcionou"? E onde está a declaração de `resources`?

Comment: eu consegui, fiz através de boolean
         boolean ok = true;

Answer (score 1):

No segundo if você esqueceu o `toString();`

faça:

```
String cnpj1 = cnpj.getText().toString();
If(!TextUtils.isEmpty(cnpj1) && cnpj1.length == 14){
   if(!isValidCnpj(cnpj1)) cnpj.setError("Mensagem"); 
}
```